# how can i select the last 90 rows from a table in sql?

Tags: sql, database

how can i select the last 90 rows from a table in sql ?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last 90 rows" from a table.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: be more specific, but am sure you want to sort in revers order depending on a column

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193705/sql-server-select-last-n-rows

Comment: Lack of details in your question but you can look for LIMIT and OFFSET SQL CLAUSE

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server SELECT LAST N Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193705/sql-server-select-last-n-rows)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE 
table_row_id > (SELECT MAX(table_row_id) - 90 FROM Table1);
```