# SQL select last 100 rows and load them into data frame via pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm using pandas to do some calculations with big data sets. I'm getting my data from a local sql-database. Now I want to select the last 100 rows of my sql table and load them into my dataframe.

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT TOP(100) * FROM testTable ORDER BY last_updated DESC', engine)
```

but it seems that my sql select command has the wrong syntax. Could you help me to correct my code?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193705/sql-server-select-last-n-rows?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: thank you, now it works.

Comment: select * from tbl_name order by id desc limit N; is the right command syntax

Comment: You absolutely need to tag and mention what RDBMS you are using (Postgres, MySQL, SQL Server, Sybase, Teradata, Oracle, etc.) as `TOP` and `LIMIT` differ among the SQL dialects.

Answer (score 0):

Try:-

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT TOP 100 * FROM testTable ORDER BY last_updated DESC', engine)
```

Brackets aren't used with TOP in some SQLs since every SQL (e.g POSTGRESQL, MYSQL, etc) has different syntax, this might be the problem perhaps