# Get all rows except last 5 rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question very similar to this one:

[SQL Server SELECT LAST N Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193705/sql-server-select-last-n-rows)

Where I need to get all rows except the last 5 rows. How can I do that?

I tried by using `row_number() over (partition by ... order by)` but it's not working

Comment: Select all rows `minus` the last N rows.... Actually, I think `EXCEPT` might be the equivalent keyword in SQL Server. But anyway, follow that concept.

Comment: can you provide me a link

Comment: If you order the data in the "wrong order" then just `OFFSET` the first 5 rows. The "last 5" are the "first 5" if in the opposite order.

Comment: really, that was not at all helpful @Marc

Comment: [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is explained here.

Comment: Be careful what you assume. What happens when there are no more than 5 rows total?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of thinking you need to omit the "last 5" all you need to if omit the first 5 in the opposite order. Then the answer is simple with an `OFFSET`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I)
ORDER BY V.I DESC
OFFSET 5 ROWS;
```

If the return order is "important" then use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT sq.I
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I)
      ORDER BY V.I DESC
      OFFSET 5 ROWS) sq
ORDER BY sq.I;
```

Comment: nice, so this offset will give me the rows excluding 5 rows and how can i fetch that 5 rows remaining

Comment: Using `TOP` @Jan . A simple search would give that the answer to *that* question.

Comment: If this answers the question, please do consider marking it as the solution so that future readers know it was useful, @Jan .

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))V(I)
EXCEPT
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT TOP 3 * 
      FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))X(I)
      ORDER BY I DESC) X;
```

result:

```
I
-----------
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```