# select bottom rows in natural order

Tags: sql-server

How can I select the bottom X rows of a table, based on natural order?  I can't do "ORDER BY DESC...", since I'm not ordering it by any column number...

I'm using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Comment: good question. +1. It is weird that SQLServer does not provide a BOTTOM (in constrast with TOP) option to retrieve last rows.

Comment: There is no such concept as a "natural order" in SQL Server; the optimizer will return rows in the matter in which it deems most effecient, which will usually (but not always) correspond to the clustered index.  As answers below have pointed out, there's no guarantee that the index will remain, and there's also no guarantee that the clustered index will be used by the optimizer.  If you assume that there's an order to your data, and that order is important, then you need to include an ORDER BY clause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQL doesn't guarantee the order of rows in a table. It only guarantees the order of rows in a query with an explicit `ORDER BY`. It's not wise to rely on a clustered index, either. A clustered index might be changed or dropped for good reasons, bad reasons, or no reason at all. Also, the query optimizer isn't guaranteed to return rows in the same order as a clustered index. In the absence of an explicit `ORDER BY`, it's not guaranteed to return rows in the same order from one run to the next. (The optimizer can make different decisions whenever it thinks it should.) Any one of those things can break your code.

Instead, use a query. Sort descending on a timestamp column. (`ORDER BY mytimestampcolumn DESC`) You can nip the top 'n' rows off that. Since you sort descending, the top rows are the bottom rows. (Couldn't resist.)

Failing a timestamp column, you might try the same with an auto-incrementing id number column, although they're not guaranteed to be in strictly chronological order. (The transaction that gets id number 1000 might commit before the transactions that got numbers 999 and 998.)

Answer (score 1):

I was faced with something similar. I have a generated file that contains data I needed to process every other day. So I made a SQL linked-server connection via a text ODBC DSN driver to it. This meant that the above repsonses about setting indicies don't really apply - as the data is just "as is".

As another gotcha - I MUST preserve the ordering of the rows, so if I do a `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY X PARITION BY Y)` it will "distort" the data (ie: change the row sequence).

So what to do?

After a bit of pondering - I wondered if MSSQLSERVER would preserve the ordering of the data if it had the same thing to sort on in every row, so:

```
with data as (0 as dummy, * from MyTable) 
select row_number() over (order by dummy) as rowID,
myTable.fieldA, myTable.fieldB from myTable
```

.. and this seems to give a natural-order rownumber, or at least a close approximation to it.

Anyway - hope this helps someone out!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a "clustered index" on your table the table is in that order.  If the table has not clustered index there is no order to the table (it is a heap table).

If it is a heap table I don't know how to get the last x rows... if it has a clustered index you can just order by list the clustered index column(s) and you will get the last x records... whoops... um... assuming you put them in in clustred index order ie autoincrimenting integer... sorry need to think about this more...

[see this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311054/how-do-i-select-last-5-rows-in-a-table-without-sorting)

Comment: Hi Josobo - yep, I do have a clustered index.

Comment: There's no guarantee, at all, that a table will be returned in the order of the clustered index, even if there is one. In the absence of an ORDER BY the query engine is (per Catcall's answer) free to return results in any order it chooses. This order can even change from one execution to another, as statistics on the table are recomputed and so on.

Comment: Cowan if you voted me down you should reread my answer! I said if you order by the clustered index in your query  and your clustered index is in the order you add the records ie auto incrimenting int... THEN YOU ARE guaranteed to get the records back in that order.  Then I pointed him to a much more detailed question/answer about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Kim's original question states that ORDER BY DESC is not possible in this case. However, he stated in a comment that he has a clustered index. Therefore, he can do ORDER BY DESC.

```
SELECT TOP xxx *
FROM blah
ORDER BY col1, col2, etc DESC
```