# Select last record without any knowledge about column name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I know, we can use scope identity, or top 1 with order by column name desc, then will give a last record.

But I want like this:

```
SELECT [LAST RECORD] * FROM [TABLE NAME]   --> without any WHERE and ORDER
```

Can MSSQL do it ?

Comment: Oh, so, that mean, anyway I must ORDER BY or get last identity for WHERE ... Teeheee, so sad, but I always do like that. I just want to know if there is a better way without sort records.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I was just noting recently in another question, SQL tables have no inherent order. There's no such thing as the "last record" until the table has been sorted.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061595/select-bottom-rows-in-natural-order/5061707#5061707)?

Comment: Oh, so, that mean, anyway I must ORDER BY or get last identity for WHERE ... Teeheee, so sad, but I always do like that. I just want to know if there is a better way without sort records.

Comment: @Tim: Different answer, but same idea!

Comment: @ken - the records are unordered in the database.  They may display to you in the same order most of the time (likely clustered index key order) but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: fetching TOP 1 rows will not result in sorting in SQL server. sorting is meant to sort all records which has cost of `O (n log (n))`. but finding TOP 1 is like finding minimum or maximum of a record set which has a cost of  `Theta (n)`.