# query - select data by first inserted

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select bottom rows in natural order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061595/select-bottom-rows-in-natural-order)

People imagine that i have this table :

**persons**

columns  of the table are         NAME and ID

and i insert this

```
insert into persons values ('name','id');

insert into persons values ('John','1');

insert into persons values ('Jack','3');

insert into persons values ('Alice','2');
```

How can i select this information order by the insertion? My query would like :

**NAME**  **ID**

name        id

John         1

Jack         3

Alice        2

Without indexs (autoincrements), it's possible?

Comment: You need to be storing that info (date-time-of-insertion, too) in the table. If you use MySQL, you could have a `TIMESTAMP` column that does that automatically.

Comment: But is not possible select the data without timestamp and sequences? Because i'm working with 3 different types of DBMS (MySQL,Postgres and SQLserver)

 the postgres select * from tablename gives me the result that i want, but in MySQL and SQLServer not.

Comment: no. not possible. you can use default(getdate())?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee that a `SELECT` statement without an `ORDER BY` will return the result in any specific order. What you see in Postgres in only coincidence. It may not happen the next time. Or when your table has 20K rows. Or when your query has a `WHERE`.

Comment: MySQL, Postgres and SQLserver

Comment: @unpix there really is no way to *ensure* this without `AUTOINCREMENT` (MySQL), `IDENTITY` (MSSQL), `SEQUENCE` (PostgreSQL) ... or some time-based column that is set at insert.

Comment: Thanks, i will modify my code ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure its not. From my knowldege sql data order is not sequetional with respect to insertion. The only idea I have is along with each insertion have a timestamp and sort by that time stamp

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible without adding a column or table containing a timestamp. You could add a timestamp column or create another table containing IDs and a timestamp and insert in to that at the same time.

Comment: Technically it could be anything sequential (e.g., a SEQUENCE value), it wouldn't necessarily have to be a timestamp.  But you are correct that there is no way to guarantee this result in SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have any assumptions about how the DBMS will store data and retrieve them without specifying `order by` clause. I.e. PostgreSQL uses MVCC and if you update any row, physically a new copy of a row will be created at the end of a table datafile. Using a plain `select` causes pg to use sequence scan scenario - it means that the last updated row will be returned as the last one.

Comment: Yes, i knew that. But thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have to agree with the other answers, Without a specific field/column todo this... well its a unreliable way... While i have not actually ever had a table without an index before i think..

you will need something to index it by, You can go with many other approaches and methods... For example, you use some form of concat/join of strings and then split/separate the query results later.

--EDIT--
For what reason do you wish not to use these methods? time/autoinc

Answer (score 0):

Without storing some sort of order information during insert, the database does not automatically keep track of every record ever inserted and their order (this is probably a good thing ;) ).  Autoincrement cannot be avoided... even with timestamp, they can hold same value.

Comment: Just be careful with terminology - `datetime` containing a "time stamp" and `timestamp` are two very different things.