# How to get Last 5 inserted/modified rows in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a very basic database and my requirement is that whenever the app comesup it should show latest n additions (rows added) in the database. 
Additions should also cover replacing values in existing rows..

Think of a console where you are showing lastest 100 modifications to the DB.

To keep the size of db small I am not including a timestamp.

Is there anyeasy way to do it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/311054/how-do-i-select-last-5-rows-in-a-table-without-sorting

Comment: He needs to be more specific about his definition of 'last'. The duplicate-link is also ambiguous about 'last'. If they both mean 'the bottom 5 rows' then it's a dup, but remember that SQL doesn't have to insert them in any order so the most recent rows could be at the bottom of the table.

Comment: I have editied the question. So it should now not seen as dup

Comment: This question should not be seen as duplicate anymore, here the @mSO wants to know the last 5 inserted/modified rows in the table, not the last 5 rows that are present in the table. The question given in the link for duplicate doesn't even make sense, logically speaking isn't sql a storage without order?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like:

```
String query= "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 0,5";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROWID,* FROM [table] ORDER BY ROWID DESC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: How to get updates in existing rows

Comment: if you need to get the last 5 updated rows, you will need to include a timestamp field and update it on every modification on this row.

Comment: I see this for first time - unaccepted answer because of changing the topic of the whole question

Comment: oops my bad. I didnt used correct terms