# How to visible only the last row of a row group of a table in ssrs report

Tags: ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a table in SSRS report. And I need to display only the last row of the table. ie, 
[image: Please refer the Image below]

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you have any grouping on your rows or columns?

Comment: Yes. Row group is there

Comment: You really need to provide a bit more info. Edit your question to show your row group and describe how you order this group. It's not easy to answer your question with so little to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can select the last row of the table by using Last() method.
For eg. if we have a table called Test then,

```
Last(Fields!Test.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[How do I select last 5 rows in a table without sorting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311054/how-do-i-select-last-5-rows-in-a-table-without-sorting) see this post, and change to "-1"

Comment: The value in the table is dynamic. It can change.